# How to store indices in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find certain segments of a string and store them, however, I will need to store a large number of these strings and I was thinking that it might be more elegant to store them as indices of the master string rather than as a list of strings. I am having trouble retrieving the indices for use. For example:

```
index1 = [0:3, 4:8] #invalid syntax
index2 = ['0:3','5:6']

s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'

print(s[index2[0]]) #TypeError string indices must be integers
```

Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you store substrings and not indices - isn't this how Python will store them internally anyway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colon-based slicing syntax is only valid inside the indexing operator, e.g. `x[i:j]`. Instead, you can store `slice` objects in your list, where `slice(x,y,z)` is equivalent to `x:y:z`, e.g.

```
index = [slice(0,3), slice(5,6)]
print([s[i] for i in index])
```

will print:

```
['ABC', 'F']
```

Answer (score 4):

Your idea of storing indices instead of actual substrings is a good one.

As for the mechanism, you should store the (start, end) numbers as a tuple of two integers:

```
index1 = [(0,3), (4,8)]
```

When it's time to reproduce the substring, write code like this:

```
pair = index1[0]  # (0,3)
sub = s[pair[0] : pair[1]]  # 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct. There is just a minor mistake that you have specified indexes in index2 list as a string so in order to extract string from them you have to convert back to integer so write

```
index2 = ['0:3','5:6']

s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'

print(s[int(index2[0][0]):int(index2[0][2])])
```